# Настройка планировщика на подключение флешки

Tags: windows, powershell, task, wmi, background-task

Надо сделать, чтобы при подключении определенной флешки запускалась программа. В интернете пишут, что можно через планировщик, но никто не пишет, как именно.

Comment: Обязательно через планировщик? WMI не подойдёт?

Comment: Да любой способ, главное чтоб программа запускалась, она находится на компьютере, не на флешке. Расскажите пожалуйста о вашем способе

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я слегка слукавил, без планировщика не обойтись, хотя, наверное, можно и через автозагрузку решить всё это.

Я для одного пожилого сотрудника когда-то использовал вот такой скрипт, который срабатывал, если вставлялась флэшка, автоопределяемая с буквой T и меткой "BP_flahka". Если буква диска не важна, то вместо `if ($driveLetter -eq 'T:' -and $driveLabel -eq 'BP_flashka')` можно использовать просто `if ($driveLabel -eq 'ТутМеткаВашейФлэшки')`. Код скрипта:

```
#Requires -version 2.0
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
do{
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
$eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
$eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
{
1 {"Configuration changed"}
2 {"Device arrival"}
3 {"Device removal"}
4 {"docking"}
}
write-host (get-date -format s) " Event detected = " $eventTypeName
if ($eventType -eq 2)
{
$driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
$driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
write-host (get-date -format s) " Drive name = " $driveLetter
write-host (get-date -format s) " Drive label = " $driveLabel
# Запустить, если буква диска и метка совпали с нужными значениями
if ($driveLetter -eq 'T:' -and $driveLabel -eq 'BP_flashka')
{
write-host (get-date -format s) " Starting task in 3 seconds..."
start-sleep -seconds 3
start-process "E:\sync.bat"
}
}
Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) #Идём в цикле дальше
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Дальше всё просто. В планировщике создаём новое задание, с такими параметрами:
**Триггер**: At log on
**Действие**: Start a program
**Program/script**: powershell
**Аргументы**: -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "Диск:\Путь\имя файла со скриптом.ps1"

**Update 1.**

Проверок для вставляемого хранилища можно устроить массу. Например:

```
   # узнаем тип файловой системы флэшки
   $fileSystem = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").FileSystem
   # проверяем, сколько свободного места осталось (в байтах) на флэшке
   $freeSpace = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").FreeSpace
   # или общий размер всей флэшки:
   $size = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").Size
   # и так далее, а затем просто проверяем нужный нам параметр, например:
   if ($fileSystem -eq 'NTFS')
     {
   # в этом случае бэкап можно делать одним большим файлом
   }
   # и так далее
```

**Update 2.** Работать будет, начиная с Windows Vista/Server 2008

**Update 3.**  Есть подозрение, что на Windows 11 скрипт может выдать ошибку в том случае, если подключаемый диск/флэшка нуждается в проверке (то есть взведён флаг VolumeDirty). Допускаю, что это особенности недавнего обновления, будет ли так и в последующих обновлениях, мне не известно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вот вопрос ещё, а можно вместо буквы и метки, vid флешки определять

Comment: Или вообще ничего не определял

Comment: @Hairy Класс Win32_LogicalDisk имеет следующие свойства: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx  Вы можете использовать вместо VolumeName всё, что вам нравится