# Имя флешки и серийный номер

Tags: python, usb, wmi

Не получается узнать имя диска(C,D,E...) и серийный номер одновременно.
Есть код для получения серийного номера и код для получения имени диска.
ОС:Windiws

Серийный номер:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

for drive in c.Win32_DiskDrive():
    print("Description: "+ drive.Description)
    print("InterfaceType: " + drive.InterfaceType)
    print("Model: " + drive.Model)
    print("SerialNumber: "+drive.SerialNumber)
    print("DeviceID: "+ drive.DeviceID)
    #print(drive.Caption)
    print("\n")
```

Имя диска:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk():
   print(disk.DeviceID)
```

Как получить одновременно имя диска (или просто название флешки) и серийный номер?

Comment: Можно (с небольшими костылями) через WMI - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759050/

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно сопоставить логические разделы физическим носителям:

```
logical_disks = {}
for drive in c.Win32_DiskDrive():
    for partition in drive.associators("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"):
        for disk in partition.associators("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
            logical_disks[disk.Caption] = {"model":drive.Model, "serial":drive.SerialNumber}
        
print(logical_disks)
```

```
{'C:': {'model': 'C300-CTFDDAC128MAG ATA Device', 
        'serial': '3030303030303030313136308830323044363145'}, 
 'D:': {'model': 'Hitachi HDS723020BLA642 ATA Device', 
        'serial': '2020202020204e4d32334032334659305931444b'},
 'F:': {'model': 'Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB ATA Device', 
       'serial': '34535783474e4b30334334343339505820202020'},
 'E:': {'model': 'WDC WD30EZRZ-00Z5HB0 ATA Device', 
        'serial': '2020202057202d4443573443944e465a4c41484e'}}
```

Comment: а как выводить например только диск E и серийный номер?

Comment: @dahal07 Гм... Как и для любого словаря: `print(logical_disks["E:"]["serial"])`. Разве нет?